# Optional Values in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift, very experienced in Objective-C.

In my app, I am receiving data from a server and mapping it to an NSMutableDictionary. The reason I am using an NSMutableDictionary is that the values are not consistent coming from the server, it's a mix of strings and numbers. And that appears to break a Swift Dictionary that expects only one type of value.

Sometimes the server is not sending a value that the NSMutableDictionary is expecting and it crashes the app.

In my research, it appears that I have to check every object to see if the value exists in Swift before setting it into the NSMutableDictionary.

This is my current code:

```
  let userDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = [
            "name": data.objectForKey("name") as! String,
             ... // many more values
```

This crashes if there is no "name" value in the response from the server.

It appears the solution would be:

```
        if let nameValue = data.objectForKey("name") as! String {
           //not sure what to do in here since the var is assigned as I need
        }
           // ... check many more values   

        let userDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = [
           "name": nameValue,
           // ... assign many more values that I checked above
```

This seems like a lot of extra code to check every single value from the server. Is there a simpler solution?

Thank you for your time.

@Matt below. Here is the code in detail (took out some of the values in the userDictionary for brevity). I'm taking data from Facebook, adding additional info and saving it to Firebase:

```
 //check all of the values
        var birthdayValue:String? = "";
        if let value:String? = data.objectForKey("birthday") as? String {
            birthdayValue = value;
        }

    let userDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = [
        "name": data.objectForKey("name") as! String,
        "birthday": birthdayValue!,
        "email": data.objectForKey("email") as! String,
        "firstName": data.objectForKey("first_name") as! String,
        "lastName": data.objectForKey("last_name") as! String,
        "description": "",
        "distance": 50,
        "facebookID": data.objectForKey("id") as! String,
        "location":[ 37.12314, -122.49182 ], //TODO: Get location
        "points" : 0,
        "rating" : 1,
        "school" : "",
    ]


    //we need to convert the FB profile pic to a base 64 string and add it here
    let imagePath:String = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(data.objectForKey("id") as! String)/picture?width=375&height=667"
    self.getDataFromUrl(NSURL(string: imagePath)!) { (imageData, response, error) -> Void in

        //convert the data to base 64
        let imgString:String = self.convertDataToBase64(imageData);
        let images:Array<String> = [imgString];

        userDictionary.setValue(images, forKey: "profilePics")

        //save the user to Firebase
        userRef.childByAppendingPath(data.objectForKey("id") as! String).setValue(userDictionary)

        self.currentUserID = (data.objectForKey("id")) as! String

    }
```

Comment: Well, how would you do it in Objective-C? If the key is not present in the `data` dictionary, you will get `nil`, and you can't put `nil` into your `userDictionary`. So you would have to "check every single value" in Objective-C too. So what's the problem?

Comment: Why not use a swift dictionary with type `[String : AnyObject?]`

Comment: Could you please show what sort of thing `data` is? The fact that you are even calling `objectForKey` is unSwifty. It would be nice to see more of what's going on here. If `data` is just a dictionary, why do you need to turn it into anything at all? Your whole exercise in pulling out the data bit by bit and putting it into an NSMutableDictionary makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Matt, you are correct about checking the values in Obj-C too... but of a brain fart here as I am trying to wrap my head around Swift Dictionaries. I added the code above that shows the data I am mapping.

Comment: If you just want to know how a Swift dictionary works, you might glance at my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_dictionary especially the section about how Swift dictionaries interface with NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: You still didn't really answer my question. Your new code snippet starts with a comment: "check all the values". But that is exactly what is at issue: the values of _what_, and _why_?

Answer (score 0):

Swift actually support *multiple* types in a dictionary. The following is legal.

```
let arr: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [1: "hello", "a": 19, 2: "Swift"]
```

And you can store optional object in the dictionary:

```
let arr: [NSObject: AnyObject?] = [1: "hello", "a": 19, 2: nil]
```

And yes, you might need to check the existence of the value if you do care about it. Instead of `if`, I would use `guard` to make sure you can use the variable later.

```
guard let nameValue = data.objectForKey("name") as? String else {
    return
}

// Now you can safely use nameValue.
```

Comment: It's good to know that Swift Dictionaries do support multiple types (thanks). However, I'm still getting a crash for the nil key/value using the let arr: [NSObject: AnyObject?] code. It's actually more than just a nil value, the key isn't coming back.

Comment: @BuyinBrian If you're adding new key value pairs to the dict, you need `var dict: [NSObject: AnyObject?] = [:]`.

Comment: You don't want to say `{return}`; he doesn't want to fail the whole thing just because he's missing one key.

Comment: No need to get personal. My comment is about the content of the answer, not about you. But pedagogically it's not helpful to show false code to the OP, esp. when he seems basically to know no Swift. The idea is to show code that will in fact work for what the OP is trying to do (whatever it is).

Answer (score 0):

> In my app, I am receiving data from a server and mapping it to an NSMutableDictionary

There is no need for this at all. The data is coming to you *as* a dictionary (at least I presume it is; if it weren't, you could hardly be calling `objectForKey`, it seems to me). So now just proceed to use it. There is nothing to "map".

For example, suppose that `data` is the result of calling NSJSONSerialization's `JSONObjectWithData:options:` on an original NSData `d`. And suppose what you expect this to serialize to is a dictionary. So after you've said

```
var data = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
    d, options:[]) as! [NSObject:AnyObject]
```

...you are *finished*: that's a mutable dictionary and you are off to the races.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a mix of strings and numbers you could perhaps try to store it as `AnyObject` in the dictionary, e.g. `[String: AnyObject]`

Then you could just try to save your data like this:

```
var userDictionary: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
userDictionary["name"] = data.objectForKey("name")
```

And when you need to access it:

```
if let name = userDictionary["name"] as? String {
    // Do something with name
}
```

If you don't want to save it as `AnyObject` I'd suggest you create a struct instead.

Answer (score -1):

`as!` is a force downcast, which causes an exception if this downcast isn't possible (which obviously is the case if the value is `nil`). `as?`, on the other hand, only downcasts where possible, and results in `nil` otherwise (which sounds like what you want).

```
let userDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = [
        "name": data.objectForKey("name") as? String,
        ... // many more values
]
```

This should work.

Edit: Never mind, this would only work if you'd use a native Swift dictionary. It's still useful to know about the difference between `as?` and `as!`, though.

Comment: You can't put optionals in an `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: It's not rudeness. What's with everyone tonight? The code you have provided would not even compile. That's not about you, it's just a fact about the code.